# Scipy Kmeans and Kmeans2 and Sklearn KMeans

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have a big matrix with dimensions 2.000X98.000 and i want to perform unsupervised clustering on it. My problem is that when i try the clustering with Scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2, i get an error that says "Matrix is not positive definite", when I try it with scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans it takes hours and hours to calculate and when i try it with sklearn.cluster.KMeans, the computation is fast and presents no errors. I have read the documentation for all the algorithms and i have researched through the internet for answers , but still i cannot understand this kind of difference between the three of them. Could someone explain to me this fundamental difference between them and why the need of a positive definite matrix is necessary only for scipy.kmeans2? Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: I can't find a `scipy.kmeans2`. Do you mean `scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2`? Do you have a backtrace? Any chance it is due to the initialization method? Have you tried `minit="points"`?

Comment: yes, i meant this and i edited my original post. I tried it many times, in order to get different initialization values but the results remains the same. I also tried this and the result still is the same.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace of the error? Btw, your question still says `scipy.kmeans2` everywhere.

Comment: @gelazari I am also facing the same error. You had any success with this issue?